# @RequestBody as a String is not being validated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I do have simple controller which accept String as `RequestBody`

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ResponseEntity doSmth(@RequestBody @ValidTest String val) {

    //do something
    return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body("saved");
  }
```

But for some reason `val` param not being validated with `TestConstraintValidator.class`

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = TestConstraintValidator.class)
@Target({PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidTest{
    String message() default "Invalid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Is there even option to validate this? Or do I need to wrap this String withing custom class. And validate it there?

```
public class TestConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidTest, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidTest constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String val, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
       
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code inside `TestConstraintValidator` is not getting triggered? can you post the code pls?

Comment: @ALex yes, I am sure. I have changed `@ResponseBody` to custom object, which has only one field. And on top of this filed I added annotation and it has started working. But as my post state, I didnt want to wrap it in object

Comment: The easiest is to create a wrapper object to contain the content, or write a spring validator and manually do the validation/binding. Also make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency and don't mess around with `validation-api` etc. yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the controller class is marked as [`@Validated`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html).

Comment: Unfortunatelly it has not worked. Same goes if I add `@Valid` to method arguments

Comment: ALthough that should make it work, the case for `@Validated` on a class is different.

Comment: @Suule I literally copied the code from the question and added `@Validated` **on top of the controller class** and it worked correctly. Can you provide your entire controller class?